# From Google Chrome Extension to Firefox Extension

Tags: firefox-addon

I have the following chrome extension codes and i want to know how to convert it in firefox extension
here are the code files.

***manifest.json***

```
{
"name": "iFB invite your friends in Facebook Events",


"version": "1.0",



"manifest_version": 2,



"permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

***background.js***

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
allFrames: true,
    file: "content_script.js"
}, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
});
});
```

***content_script.js***

```
var x=document.querySelectorAll("._1v30.clearfix ._1v34");

y=1;


for(var i in x) 


{if(y<5000){x[i].click();

y++;}


else{break;}
}
```

any ideas or any usefull converter???

Comment: You can now use webextensions api to get this done. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions

Comment: @Noitidart As far as i can see it uses the same code as chrome, right?

Comment: but since then i have changed a lot the code but anyway thank you very much man :D